# Mouse event to collision as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouse, collision

Hello I am trying to convert this as3 code, which is a mouse event code into collision event. I am sorry, but I don't know where in the code to put the other object with instance name mcBall.

```
tile1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tileClick);


function tileClick(e:MouseEvent):void {

MovieClip(e.currentTarget).gotoAndStop(2);
if(tile1.currentFrame == 1) return;


gotoAndStop(5);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, can you elaborate? Also, note this line will NEVER execute: if(tile1.currentFrame == 1) return;. CurrentFrame will be always 2 (you are making a call to gotoAndStop(2) just above it).

Comment: I am trying to go to frame 2 inside the tile mc when the tile hits the ball and then when the tilemc is cleared (on frame 2 there is (visible=false command) to go to frame 5 on the main timeline. This is a working example as Mouse event, so I am trying to make this happen on collision. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it working.

firstly I made layers 'actions' and 'cont' run all 5 frames and copied 'mcPaddle' & 'ball' to layer1's (keyframe) on (frame 5).

on your actions layer I added this at the top of your code.

```
var BricksRemoved=int(0);
var newBricksRemoved=BricksRemoved;

function RemoveBrick(e:Event=null):void{
    newBricksRemoved=newBricksRemoved+1;
    if(newBricksRemoved==2)
        {gotoAndStop(5)}
    }

function TraceBricksRemoved(e:Event=null):void{
    trace(newBricksRemoved);
    }
```

and added the following code inside brick 2, frame 2:

```
    Object(root).RemoveBrick();
    Object(root).TraceBricksRemoved();
    Object(root).Cont.removeChild(this.tile2);
```

And in Brick4, Frame 2, I added

```
    Object(root).RemoveBrick();
    Object(root).TraceBricksRemoved();
    Object(root).Cont.removeChild(this.tile1);
```

in case I forgot something, I will upload source to my server: http://www.dialoz.com/FLA_Source/Break4.fla

Comment: This is different approach which is I think is complicating the problem and am not sure as to how it would work. The code has to be inside a container mc, called "Cont" and when the tiles (2 or more) hit the ball should go to frame 5 on the main timeline. That is all I am trying to achieve (for already a month). This is the file: https://app.box.com/s/kd5eu1ipa9jvzppbg7yj. Thanks

Comment: OK got it working & Have update my answer above.   Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. It does not work with cs6. I get 2007 error. Parameter object must be non null. And there is problem with the function detectplayer inside tile1 and 2, which serves the purpose to detect the ball. Should i remove that function along with the event listener?  Is there any way the code you added on the main timeline to be put in the Cont mc?

Comment: I probably shouldn't dismiss this error, however in cases like this I just ignore the 2007 error.  it doesn't prevent you from Publishing SWF and to test in flash with out annoying 'Error" 'Continue' etc. I just use 'CTRL+ENTER'  instead of 'CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER'.  Publish SWF & you will see All Is Working.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me. I will not be able to use it because I am planning to add many things and I don't want to look this error every time the ball hits the tile, I did not ask the question properly anyway. Still there has to be a way to be done without mistakes. I'll post another question for collision specifically.